# Name the Third Friend

Tags: lateral-thinking

Three friends were discussing their favorite things.

> Tuweth declared that he loved camels.
>   Sumo stated that she loved the going to church and to work.
>   The third said that they loved to party, and liked to boogie down.

The next week, they discussed the solar system.

> Tuweth discussed Mars, Mercury and Jupiter.
>   Sumo extolled the virtues of the sun and moon.
>   The third person said, "But what about Venus and Saturn, aren't they the best parts?"

**What was the name of the third friend?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Would that be, perhaps:

> Frisa? That'd be beacuse "Tuweth" stands for Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday, while Sumo stands for Sunday and Monday. Given that the days are always named in order, that would leave "Friday" and "Saturday", merged as Frisa.

Edit:

> As pointed out by @Soltius, the listed activities seem to corroborate this theory. And, by the way, I guess "camel" it's a reference to the common expression "hump day", which means "mid-week day" (like Wednesday).

Comment: I think you're right. Moreover, the activities listes in the first dialog (haven't got the camel part,, though..), and the planets listed in the second one corroborate with your answer.

Comment: I've just made an edit to the answer to try to explain that.

Answer (score 7):

> To add to KamiV's answer, there are even more clues in the second part of the story. 
>  **Mar**s, **Merc**ury, and **Ju**piter correspond to the French words for Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday: Mardi, Mercredi, et Jeudi. 
>  The same applies to **Ven**us and **Sa**turn, as Friday and Saturday translate to Vendredi et Samedi.

Comment: I was actually thinking in Spanish: rot13(Znef, Zrephel, Whcvgre, Irahf, Fnghea : **Zne**grf, **Z**v**rep**byrf, **Wh**rirf, **I**v**r**e**a**r**f**, **Fn**onqb). Guess it works in French too!

Comment: To be honest, i always thought that rot13(gur bevtva bs Fngheqnl, Fhaqnl naq Zbaqnl ner nyy cynargnel obqvrf:(Fngheqnl = Fnghea'f Qnl; Fhaqnl = Fha'f Qnl; Zbaqnl = Zbba'f Qnl)). I couldn't really connect the others though